# Phonegap: Como salvar no Banco uma imagem tirada e transformada em base64?

Tags: php, javascript, ajax, apache-cordova, base64

Eu tiro uma foto com uma aplicação android e transformo em base64, gostaria de saber como faço pra salvar esse base64 no banco junto com outras informações que eu tenho na página...

Esse é o meu código que tira as fotos e transforma em base64:

```
var pictureSource;   // picture source
var destinationType; // sets the format of returned value


document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady,false);
document.addEventListener("deviceready",onDeviceReady2,false);


function onDeviceReady() {
  pictureSource=navigator.camera.PictureSourceType;
  destinationType=navigator.camera.DestinationType;

}

 function onDeviceReady2() {
 navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(onSuccess, onError);
}

function onPhotoDataSuccess(imageData) {

var smallImage = document.getElementById('smallImage');

smallImage.style.display = 'block';

smallImage.src = "data:img/jpeg;base64," + imageData; 

}


function capturePhoto() {

navigator.camera.getPicture(onPhotoDataSuccess, onFail, { 
quality: 60,
destinationType: destinationType.DATA_URL,
allowEdit: true,
correctOrientation: true,
sourceType: Camera.PictureSourceType.CAMERA,
encodingType: Camera.EncodingType.JPEG,
targetWidth: 3000,
saveToPhotoAlbum:1

 });
}

function onFail(message) {
alert('Failed because: ' + message);
}
```

Essa função irei chamar através de um botão e ela irá enviar os dados de um formulário,minha localização e a imagem tirada(mas estou enviando a imagem de forma errada)

```
function enviar(){
  var formula = $('#formCliente').serialize();
  var lon = document.getElementById("myDivLo").innerHTML;
  var lat = document.getElementById("myDivL").innerHTML;
  var img = document.getElementById('smallImage').innerHTML;


 $.ajax({

  type:'POST',
  data:formula + ' &lat=' + lat  + "&lon=" + lon+ "&img=" + img ,

    url:'http://ip/teste/www/criar_incidente_camera.php',

 success: function(data){


 if(data == '' || data == 0){
     alert('Usuário ou senha incorreto' + data);   
     window.location = "";
 }

if(data == 1){
     window.location.href = "mapa_incidente.html";   
    }

    else{
         alert('outro' + data); 
       }


     }


  });

}
</script>
```

Inserindo valores no banco:

```
 $sql = 'INSERT INTO incidente (titulo, descricao, anonimo, tipo,   
 latitude, longitude, foto)';
 $sql .= 'VALUES (:titulo, :descricao, :anonimo, :tipo, :latitude, 
 :longitude, :foto)';

try {

$recebeConexao = $pdo->prepare($sql);

$recebeConexao->bindParam(':titulo', $_POST['titulo'], 
PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':descricao', $_POST['descricao'], 
PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':anonimo', $_POST['anonimo'], 
PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':tipo', $_POST['tipo'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':latitude', $_POST['lat'], PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':longitude', $_POST['lon'], 
PDO::PARAM_STR);
$recebeConexao->bindParam(':foto', $_POST['img'], PDO::PARAM_STR);



  $recebeConexao->execute();

  if($recebeConexao == true){

  $cadastro = 1;
 }else{
 $cadastro = 0;
}


} catch (PDOException $ex) {
echo "Erro inserção";
}



echo (json_encode($cadastro));
```

Estou usando no Banco BLOB para armazenar a imagem... Obrigada!

Comment: @MarcosRegis   Desculpe a pergunta, mas sou nova em programação...Nessa parte do código que você mostrou:
    form.append('fotos[]', fileInput.files[0]);
No lugar de 'fotos[]' eu colocaria o 'smallImage' do meu código?

Comment: Ignora a mensagem anterior. É preciso ver o que está chegando em `http://ip/teste/www/criar_incidente_camera.php` Como está recuperando as informações??

Comment: @MarcosRegis Você quer saber como está meu arquivo php? Se for eu editei acima e inseri a parte do php.

Comment: No caso, se está em base64 o campo não precisa ser BLOB. Conseguiu gravar alguma informação no Banco de Dados? Debuga a variavel $_POST pra ver o que tem nela quando tenta enviar os dados.

Comment: Todas as outras informações que estou enviando estão sendo salvas no banco, somente a foto(base64) que não consigo salvar...

Comment: deve ser problema de serialização...

Comment: Por que os votos negativos nessa pergunta?

Answer (score 0):

Na sua função `onPhotoDataSuccess` você guarda os dados base64 no `src` do elemento `smallImage`:

```
smallImage.src = "data:img/jpeg;base64," + imageData;
```

Mas na função `enviar` você está pegando o `innerHTML` desse elemento e enviando via Ajax:

```
var img = document.getElementById('smallImage').innerHTML;

$.ajax({

  type:'POST',
  data:formula + ' &lat=' + lat  + "&lon=" + lon+ "&img=" + img ,
```

Suponho então que esse valor esteja indo vazio, antes mesmo de chegar ao servidor. Envie o valor de `src`, e esse problema em particular (de não salvar nada no banco) deve resolver (se há outros problemas ou não com o campo BLOB, não sei dizer):

```
var img = document.getElementById('smallImage').src;
```

Comment: Tentei mudar pra src, mas não funcionou :/

Comment: @AmandaPistolato Ok, mas ao menos os dados estão indo pro servidor? Tipo, se você fizer `console.log(img)` o que aparece no console do *browser*? Ou, no lado PHP, se você imprimir `$_POST['img']` em algum lugar, o que aparece?

Answer (score -1):

de forma simplificada, você pode armazenar a imagem usando dentro da função onPhotoDataSuccess:
    localStorage.setItem("imageURI", imageURI);

e depois basta recuperar o valor antes de fazer a chamada AJAX:

```
var img = localStorage.getItem("imageURI");

$.ajax({
type:'POST',
data:formula + ' &lat=' + lat  + "&lon=" + lon+ "&img=" + img ,
```